# Populate conditional column depending on column name criteria

Tags: powerquery, m

I receive a weekly report which contains some repetition of columns.  This is because it is drawn from a collection of web forms which ask similar questions to each other - let's say they all ask "**Do you want to join our email list?**" - but this question is stored in the source system as a separate field for each form (each form is effectively a separate table).  The columns will always be consistently named - e.g. "Email_optin_1", "Email_optin_2" - so I can come up with rules to identify the columns which ask the email question.  However, the number of columns may vary from week to week - one week the report might just contain "Email_optin_2", the next week it might include four such columns. (This depends on which web-forms have been used in that week).  The possible values are the same in all these columns - let's say "**Yes**" and "**No**".

Each row should normally only have one of the "Email_optin" columns populated.

What I would like to do is create a single column in Power Query called "Email_Optin_FINAL", which would return "Yes" if ANY columns beginning with "Email_optin" contain a value of "Yes".

So, basically, instead of the criteria simply referring to the values in specific columns, what I would like it to do is first of all figure out **which columns** it needs to be looking at, and then look at the values in those columns.

Is this possible in PowerQuery?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. The key-concept for the sollution is probably unpivotting the weekly reports. Could you give an example of such a weekly report and a sample of what the endresult should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would find all the columns containing Email_optin and merge them for you into a new column and remove the original columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
EmailList= List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Text.Contains(_, "Email_optin")),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source,EmailList,Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in #"Merged Columns"
```

This would find all the columns containing Email_optin and merge them for you into a new column and preserve the original columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Index= Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
EmailList= List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Index), each Text.Contains(_, "Email_optin")),   
Merged = Table.CombineColumns(Index,EmailList,Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Index,{"Index"},Merged,{"Index"},"Merged",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Merged", {"Merged"}, {"Merged"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table2",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

you can then filter for "YES" among the merged answers if you want

Comment: Thanks so much - I need to test this out next week and will let you know how it worked!

Comment: YESSSS!  Worked like an absolute dream.  Sorry it took so long to reply - I did test it out a few weeks ago and obviously did something wrong as I kept getting error msgs, but I tried it again today and it is PERFECT.  This will save me so much time!  Thanks so very much.

Comment: I thought I did?  I've ticked it as correct and clicked the "up" button too.  Is there something else that needs doing?